# Weird issue of internet connectivity when starting Old meteor app 1.5 with Fresh Meteor 1.6.1.1 Installation

Tags: meteor

I have developed a Meteor App on version 1.5. I did a fresh installation of Meteor using *Chocolatey* with version 1.6.1.1. Now when I run the meteor command in my project directory, I get below error:

```
D:\project_name>meteor
Sorry, this project uses Meteor 1.5, which is not installed and could not
be downloaded. Please check to make sure that you are online.
   Downloading meteor-tool@1.5.0...          |
D:\project_name>
```

I can confirm I have internet connectivity but don't know why such messages are given on the screen instead of downloading *meteor-tool@1.5.0* and running Meteor App.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The message may be confusing regarding the internet connectivity but it is rather because of the incompatible version numbers. Does it throws error when you try to update the project, for instance by setting `.meteor/release` to the one you installed?

Comment: it creates the same issue for a project created earlier in same version 1.6.1.1